# PHP Get Method, does not Enter If Statement

Tags: php, arrays, database, if-statement, get

I am not sure why it does not enter the if statement in the API class to actually execute the method. The goal of this method is to simply return a specific row of data, when entering a specific username (this is a users database that holds users info etc). Any help in the right direction is welcomed. This is fairly new stuff to me. Thanks

This is the Connect Class. It is working 100%

```
 <?php 
    class DbConnect{
    private $con;

        function __construct(){

        }

        function connect(){
            include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Constants.php';
            $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "Failed to connect with database".mysqli_connect_err();

            }
            return $this->con;

        }

    }

    <?php
```

This class handles all the functions. 
EDIT: So after more testing, I believe the error is in this part of the code.

```
class DbOperations{
    private $con;


    function __construct(){
        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }

    public function getTheSpecificUser($username){
        //$username = $_POST['username'];
        //$username = $_POST['username'];



         $stmt= $this->con-> prepare("SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, 
        `phonenumber`, `birthdate`, `lastname`, `firstname`, `middlename` 
          FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s",  $username);
        $stmt->bind_result( $id, $username, $email, $phonenumber, 
        $birthdate, $lastname, $firstname, $middlename);
        $stmt->execute();

        //$stmt->bind_result("isssssss", $id, $username, $email, 
        //$phonenumber, $birthdate,
        //$lastname, $firstname, $middlename);

$results = array();

        //$results = $stmt->fetch();

        while($stmt->fetch()){


            $result = array();
            $result['id'] = $id;
            //$result['username'] = $username;
            $result['email'] = $email;
            $result['phonenumber'] = $phonenumber;
            $result['birthdate'] = $birthdate;
            $result['lastname'] = $lastname;
            $result['firstname'] = $firstname;
            $result['middlename'] = $middlename;

            array_push($results, $result);
        }
        return $results; 


    }
```

This is the class that handles all the operations.

This is where the method is called from DbOpertaions. It is included and works correctly with other functions.

EDIT: I do not think the error is here, because if the statement is taken out of the if statement, then it should fire, but nothing happens if added to $response. So again the error must be in the DbOperaitions class.

```
<?php 

    //getting the dboperation class
    require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

    $response = array();


    if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

        switch($_GET['apicall']){


      case 'getthespecificuser':

            if(isset($_GET['username'])){
                echo "you are past the frist if statement";
                $db = new DbOperations();

                if($db->getTheSpecificUser($_GET['username'])){
                    echo "you are in the second if statement";
                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['id'] = $user['id'];
                        $response['username'] = $user['username'];
                        $response['email'] = $user['email'];
                        $response['phonenumber'] = $user['phonenumber'];
                        $response['lastname'] = $user['lastname'];
                        $response['firstname'] = $user['firstname'];
                        $response['middlename'] = $user['middlename'];



                }else{
                    echo "-->";
                    var_dump($_GET['username']);
                    die();
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "something went wrong";

                }


            }else{
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = "please enter a valid username";

            }
            break;
     }else{
        //if it is not api call 
        //pushing appropriate values to response array 
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call`enter code here`';
    }

    //displaying the response in json structure 
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: What do you have in $_GET before the if? Plese give me the output of : var_dump($_GET);

Comment: @Peter I have the persons username, this is what pops up in post man. "you are past the frist if statement-->string(3) "sss""

Comment: Just a side notice, when I glanced through the first script there seems to be a typo ("mmysqli") in: echo "Failed to connect with database".mmysqli_connect_err(); ?!

Comment: @Wooz Thank you, Appreciate you.